# Allow some processes to read and write a directory and deny rest of all processes

Tags: c, linux

I want to monitor processes and give permission for accessing a directory. I have some processes which I want to give permission access as read,write and to rest of all process deny the access to that directory.

I have a appliction in which there are multiple processess. So i want that only these processes can access a specific directory. No other processes should be able to access this directory even if running as root.

Comment: What you have tried so far..?

Comment: Hi Vikas. Why don't you add what you have tried so far and where you are having trouble?

Comment: [chmod](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)? If you are looking for something else or a more specific answer then you'll need to improve your question to describe what you have tried and make it clearer what the constraints of your desired solution are.

Comment: i have a appliction in which there are mutiple processess .so i want that only these processes can aceess a specific directory. and no other process can not access this directory event that they have capability of root user.

Comment: Look at @CoreyHenderson's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8607443/2706918), he has worked on a kernel module which does similar job.

Answer (score 2):

SELinux can do this. Simply give the directory and its contents a distinct file context, only allow access to the file context from a specific domain, and run the single process within this domain.

Comment: I want a genralized way but SELinux is not working for all linux vesions.

Comment: Sometimes life isn't neat and tidy and pretty like that.